# Accessing Usb port on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, module, usb, windows-10-iot-core

I am running an IoT Edge Module on Windows 10 IoT Core on a Minnowboard Turbot. This module needs to read a stream from a USB port. We're using System.Io.Ports (.net standard version that is compatible with our .net core 2.1 code).

I have seen this work on a laptop with Windows 10 pro, but it does not work Windows IoT Core. I can find some sources that state that System.Io.Ports is not supported on IoT Core because of the naming scheme for Usb ports (which must be called COM{x} for SerialPort to work properly. The Readme that comes with the SerialIOPrts sample from Windows IoT Samples (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=860459) says

"This sample uses standard .NET Core System.IO.Ports APIs to access the serial devices. These APIs only work with serial devices which come named COM{x}. Consequently, this approach is relevant on Windows 10 IoT Enterprise, but not Windows 10 IoT Core."

Has anyone found a way around this? I can probably get it to work on Windows 10 IoT Enterprise but I would really like to prove we can run this module on minimal hardware/os.

Answer (score 0):

Using System.IO.Ports on Windows IoT Core you can refer to "[SerialWin32 Azure IoT Edge module](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/EdgeModules/SerialWin32/CS)". (**Note:** These instructions will work on a PC running Windows 10 IoT Enterprise or Windows IoT Core build 17763. Only the **x64** architecture is supported currently. Arm32 will come in the future.)

(Not for Azure IoT Edge Module)To access serial device without port name (COMx) on Windows IoT Core you can use Win32 API [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew). There is a project template for creating a Win32 console application for Windows IoT Core you can get started.

[image]

Here I create a sample using device id to open an serial device and write and read:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    DWORD errCode = 0;
    LPCWSTR pDeviceId = L"\\\\?\\FTDIBUS#VID_0403+PID_6001+A50285BIA#0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}";

    HANDLE serialDeviceHdl = CreateFile(pDeviceId, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (!serialDeviceHdl)
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "Open device failed. Error code: " << errCode << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD writenSize = 0;
    BOOL result = WriteFile(serialDeviceHdl, "hello", 5, &writenSize, NULL);
    if (FALSE == result)
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "Write to device failed. Error code: " << errCode << endl;
    }

    CHAR readBuf[5];
    DWORD readSize = 0;
    result = ReadFile(serialDeviceHdl, readBuf, 5, &readSize, NULL);
    if (FALSE == result)
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "Read from device failed. Error code: " << errCode << endl;
    }
}
```

Device Id you can find, for example, via official sample "[SerialUART](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/SerialUART)" - "[DeviceInformation.Id](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/develop/Samples/SerialUART/CS/MainPage.xaml.cs#L88)".

How to deploy and debug win32 C++ console on Windows IoT Core you can refer to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/MemoryStatus/CPP).

Comment: Not really. I can run the module without problems, except when I use the SerialPort class from System.Io.Ports it never connects to a USB port. System.IO,Ports can only work with portnames like COM. On IoT Core Usb ports don't have those names.

Comment: @derk There are also a [SerialWin32 sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/EdgeModules/SerialWin32/CS) will work on a PC running Windows 10 IoT Enterprise or Windows IoT Core build 17763.

Comment: tnx for your effort. I have seen and tried that sample. It does enumerate the ports but it won't actually connect. I could try to debug that but also I wanted to use it as I would the SerialPort class, i.e. to get e reference to a stream, because I am porting existing code to be used as an edge module: it was built to use System.IO.Ports. I'd have to redesign a lot of it and it is somebody else's code. There is also a nuget package called "SerialPortStream", a rewrite of the Microsoft default, I wonder if that could offer a solution.

Comment: @derk That sample actually also use CreateFile to open the port. You can create a Win32 console application for Windows IoT Core as described in my answer to see if the serial port can work. If this works then try to find the error information in that sample code.